# Routing from LXC to WAN

Tags: iptables, routing, lxc

I have a VPS with one public IP, `64.x.x.x` which is assigned to `enp1s0`.

My goal is to have LXC container/s running on this VPS which have *connectivity with the host and with WAN*. That means traffic is routed from `Container > lxcbr0 > enp1s0 > WAN`
I followed the standard procedure in LXC, which creates a bridge `lxcbr0` and a veth device connected to the bridge. From the container I can ping the host and also the public IP of the host. But I can't reach WAN! As far as I know I did everything right in the configuration, but obviously I didn't.

Host:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 64.x.x.x/32 brd 64.x.x.250 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 84329sec preferred_lft 84329sec
    inet6 fe80::9400:1ff:fe0e:33dc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: lxcbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.1/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global lxcbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe00:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vethf6wBpH@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxcbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:1f:bc:2d:41:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::fc1f:bcff:fe2d:413c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


# iptables -L -t nat -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   124 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    any     10.0.3.0/24         !10.0.3.0/24   

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         17.x.x.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp1s0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
17.x.x.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp1s0

# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

# iptables -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere  
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Container:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4e:53:3c:48:56:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.0.3.25/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4c53:3cff:fe48:56ad/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.3.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I looked at `tcpdump -i lxcbr0 icmp` on the host. Ping **request** comes through, but I don't see any **reply**. `tcpdump  -i enp1s0 icmp` doesn't show any activity while I ping WAN from the container.

Appreciate all thoughts on this!

Comment: Did you enable IP forwarding at all on the host?

Comment: @A.B Yes, I had. I think the problem was a seccomp profile installed by some other software. I startet from scratch and it worked right away.